# How do I remove everything after the second colon in the second column, and keep everything else?

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have file (`file.bim`) with about 1.5 mill. lines that looks like this:

```
1   1:819959:C:T    0   819959  T   C
1   1:821249:G:A    0   821249  A   G
1   1:821477:A:G    0   821477  G   A
1   1:821843:C:T    0   821843  T   C
1   1:823963:A:C    0   823963  C   A
1   1:824357:C:T    0   824357  T   C
1   1:824398:A:C    0   824398  C   A
1   1:827972:G:A    0   827972  A   G
1   1:828539:A:T    0   828539  T   A
```

In the second column I would like to remove the second colon and the three following characters, and keep the remaining columns as they are. The desired output is as following (`updated_file.bim`):

```
1   1:819959    0   819959  T   C
1   1:821249    0   821249  A   G
1   1:821477    0   821477  G   A
1   1:821843    0   821843  T   C
1   1:823963    0   823963  C   A
1   1:824357    0   824357  T   C
1   1:824398    0   824398  C   A
1   1:827972    0   827972  A   G
1   1:828539    0   828539  T   A
```

I tried using `awk`, but here only the colons are removed, but the letters between them remain:

```
awk -F":" '{ print $1":"$2,$3,$4,$5,$6 }' file.bim > updated_file.bim
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following `awk` program:

```
awk '{sub(/:[^:]*:[^:]*$/,"",$2)}1' file.bim > updated_file.bim
```

or

```
awk '{sub(/(:[^:]*){2}$/,"",$2)}1' file.bim > updated_file.bim
```

This will use the `sub()` function to edit the second column (`$2`) by replacing the last two `:` and the text following them with "nothing", thus effectively removing that part.

If the output file should be tab-separated, use `awk -v OFS="\t" ' ... '`.

**Alternatively**, if your file is delimited by *groups of more than one "space"* and you want to ensure that the delimiter formatting is completely unchanged, you can use

```
awk '{sub(/:[^:]*:[^: ]* /," ")}1' file.bim > updated_file.bim
```

which will look for the pattern "`:`, followed by text, followed by `:`, followed by text, followed by space", and replace that one with a single "space". In your input, this pattern only occurs at the end of column 2, so that replacement will only affect that column.

**Finally**, if at any time in the future the number of `:`-separated fields in the second column can change, but you still only want to retain the first two, you can resort to my [original](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/620453/1) albeit less portable variant, which replaces the 2nd column by only the text around the first `:` (instead of the text behind the last two with "nothing"):

```
awk '{$2=gensub(/([^:]+:[^:]+).*/,"\\1","1",$2)}1' file.bim > updated_file.bim
```

Comment: This worked as desired! Thank you.

Comment: @jonandet You're welcome, glad it worked!

Comment: nbd but you could write `/(:[^:]*){2}$/` instead of `/:[^:]*:[^:]*$/`.

Comment: @EdMorton You are right of course (although it is only 1 character shorter ;) ). I had kept the notation because that program had "evolved" by minimal line-editing from my original `gensub()` approach ...

Answer (score 2):

Remove everything after the second colon in the second column and keep everything else:

```
awk '{ c=split($2, s, ":"); $2=s[1] (c>1?":":"") s[2]; }1' infile
```

as you noticed this removes the repeated whitespaces when we re-evaluate the second column if that's not the big problem on your side; else use below `sed` as an alternative:

```
sed -E 's/^([^ ]* *)([^: ]*:[^: ]*):[^ ]* (.*)/\1\2 \3/' infile
```

---

test-date;

```
::1   1:81995:9:C:T    0   8::199:59  T   C
1:a:  :1821249GA:    0   821:2:4  A   G
111   1:828539::    0   :::828539  T   A
```

result:

```
::1   1:81995    0   8::199:59  T   C
1:a:  :1821249GA    0   821:2:4  A   G
111   1:828539    0   :::828539  T   A
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed for `\S`:

```
$ sed 's/\(:[^:]*\)\S*/\1/' file
1   1:819959    0   819959  T   C
1   1:821249    0   821249  A   G
1   1:821477    0   821477  G   A
1   1:821843    0   821843  T   C
1   1:823963    0   823963  C   A
1   1:824357    0   824357  T   C
1   1:824398    0   824398  C   A
1   1:827972    0   827972  A   G
1   1:828539    0   828539  T   A
```

or with any POSIX sed:

```
$ sed 's/\(:[^:]*\)[^[:space:]]*/\1/' file
1   1:819959    0   819959  T   C
1   1:821249    0   821249  A   G
1   1:821477    0   821477  G   A
1   1:821843    0   821843  T   C
1   1:823963    0   823963  C   A
1   1:824357    0   824357  T   C
1   1:824398    0   824398  C   A
1   1:827972    0   827972  A   G
1   1:828539    0   828539  T   A
```

Comment: this doesn't consider removing from the "second column"  in case first column was containing one or more colons. example  `::1   1:81995:9:C:T    0   8::199:59  T   C`

Comment: Absolutely right, it just works for the OPs data. There's no reason to think the first field will ever have colons given the posted example.

Answer (score 0):

Use sed to replace all empty spaces with ":" then dismiss **$6** and **$7** fields and put the content of **$4** and **$5** on **$5** with awk :

```
sed  's/ /:/g' bim | awk  -F':' '{ $6=""; $7="" ; $4=$4$5; $5="" }1' > updated_file.bim
```

**WITHOUT SED :**

```
awk  '{ gsub(/ /,":",$0); FS=":";$6=""; $7="" ; $4=$4$5; $5="" }1' bim > updated_file.bim
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this will keep the letter after the last `:` in the second column.

Comment: I have made an edit :) I have used to replace spaces by ':' to keep the same width.

Comment: this removes all colons from the input as well; test with `1   1:828539:AT::    0   8:5:3:9:6:7:89:0  T   A` line as an example; also this will fail if number of whitespaces between columns were vary

Comment: I see i have added one without the use of sed   :) Your method is fine ! An upvote from my side ! With your test case  the output will be `1   1828539        0   8 5 3 9 6 7 89 0  T   A` But i think that's what it's wanted on the question !

Answer (score 0):

with `awk` first with `substr($2, 1, 8)` you select from $2 what you need. And print the value of  `s` instead of `$2`. So your code with this can be:

```
awk 's = substr($2, 1, 8) {print $1, s, $3, $4, $5, $6}' file
1 1:819959 0 819959 T C
1 1:821249 0 821249 A G
1 1:821477 0 821477 G A
1 1:821843 0 821843 T C
1 1:823963 0 823963 C A
1 1:824357 0 824357 T C
1 1:824398 0 824398 C A
1 1:827972 0 827972 A G
1 1:828539 0 828539 T A
```

Updated, for keeping the spaces:

```
awk -F '[[:blank:]]{2,}' '$2 = substr($2, 1, 8) {print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6}' file | column -t
1  1:819959  0  819959  T  C
1  1:821249  0  821249  A  G
1  1:821477  0  821477  G  A
1  1:821843  0  821843  T  C
1  1:823963  0  823963  C  A
1  1:824357  0  824357  T  C
1  1:824398  0  824398  C  A
1  1:827972  0  827972  A  G
1  1:828539  0  828539  T  A
```

Comment: This does not keep spaces :)

Comment: @Reda, see updated. Perhaps now this can help.

Comment: Yes it's good  )

Answer (score 0):

The following Output can be achieved using `sed` command

```
cat file.bim | sed 's/:[a-zA-Z]//g' >> updated_file.bim

or

cat file.bim | sed 's/:[[:alpha:]]//g' >> updated_file.bim
```

**Output :**

```
1   1:819959    0   819959  T   C
1   1:821249    0   821249  A   G
1   1:821477    0   821477  G   A
1   1:821843    0   821843  T   C
1   1:823963    0   823963  C   A
1   1:824357    0   824357  T   C
1   1:824398    0   824398  C   A
1   1:827972    0   827972  A   G
1   1:828539    0   828539  T   A
```